# Increase by 1 until end of range, then start with 1 again in R

Tags: r, radix

Hey I want to increase numbers by 1 until a certain end point, then start with 1 again. So for example:

```
end_point = 3
1 2 3 1 2 3

seq(1,end_point)
```

...does this at least one time but I want it to repeat in a loop until a certain condition is matched.

Comment: use `rep` with `length.out` argument? `rep(1:3,length.out=5)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using an if statement.

```
end_point = 3

seq(1,end_point)

check=1

some_conditions = length(c(1,2,3,1,2,3)) ## this is just to match your example, you can turn this into any condition
some_value = 0

while (check==1){
  for (i in seq(1,end_point)){
    print(i)
    some_value = some_value+1
  if (some_conditions == some_value){
    check = 0
    break}
    
  }

}
```

Essentially, the *while loop* keeps looping over the *for loop* as long as 'check' is unchanged resulting in a repetitive 1,2,3 sequence. A certain condition can be set to change the value of 'check', thus breaking the *while loop*. The *break* statement prevents it from completing the repetitive sequence.